# ASP.net range validator moving to next page

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, web, rangevalidator

I have put a range validator in a asp.net text box control in my webpage; whenever the range is not meeting ; it will dispay the error message,

But it is moving to the next page. how i can prevent it from moving to the next page after the click of submit button while the range not met??

Comment: @Jaison, please post the the ASPX code for your validator, the control you are trying to check, and the code that fires when you click "Next"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure your submit button is in the same `ValidationGroup` as your range validator. This is particularly true if you have more than one `ValidationGroup` defined.
- Make sure the property `CausesValidation` is not set to false on the button. The default value is `True` so if the property is not declared in your ASPX or code behind, the button should fire your validation sequence.
- If you are not using the normal page flow, (i.e. your button has the property `UseSubmitBehvior` set to `False`, or in some cases, when using asych AJAX callbacks) then you will want to wrap your page changing code in an `If` block which checks for `Page.IsValid` before firing.
- Double check that the `ControlToValidate` is set to the correct control and that it does not have a default value which passes the validation.

Comment: Validation group is correct; Causevalidation is set to true ;control to validate is currect ; Use submit behavior is true now ; but i didnt understand what i have to do in the code ..i am newbie here please elaborate

Comment: what you mean by wrap the page ??

Comment: @Jaison - Your Page Changing code, not the page itself. So if you have something like `response.redirect(nextPage, false);` you'll want to put that in an `If` statement so it does not fire if `Page.IsValid` returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Code?

Are you submitting directly to the next page rather than posting back to the same page and redirecting?

Are you redirecting in Page_Load, which [occurs *before* validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)?

Comment: If so, calling Page.Validate() method before might help

Comment: i am clicking a "Next" button and going to the next page i am newbie here please help